# How to use Audacious music player over SSH?

Tags: sound, ssh, pulseaudio, alsa, audacious

I want to play music on my desktop PC via SSH so that the player GUI opens on my laptop, but still use the desktop's local sound system for output. In other words only control the player remotely.

When I open a terminal with `SSH -X` and start `Audacious` the GUI opens just fine.

However, it cannot play anything via `ALSA` nor `PulseAudio`:

```
$ audacious
ALSA lib confmisc.c:855:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_inum returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:422:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1334:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5701:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib control.c:1528:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL default
...
ERROR util.cc:269 [audgui_simple_message]: ALSA error: snd_pcm_open failed: No such file or directory.
```

It naturally works when I log in to my desktop locally.

Comment: That is not simple, and I am not sure how/if is possible. `ssh -X` runs the program on the remote computer and uses your display. In the same way, as is it using your display, the program should be able to use your audio card, too. Maybe something could be done by tweaking permissions on your local pulseaudio, but if X forwarding does not support sound forwarding everything is useless. On top of that, the program on remote machine should know your audio setup. I am using ssh to play sound over network, but it is played on the remote machine, and audio file is also there.

Comment: @nobody I don't need sound forwarding. Audacious should use the local desktop machine's sound system, but it doesn't work for some reason. I only need to open the GUI remotely.

Comment: I see the question has been marked as a duplicate. Take a look at the other answer and try to do something with `PULSE_SERVER`. I hope it helps.

Comment: @nobody That duplicated problem is the same, but unfortunately the solution is over 12 years old and didn't work anymore as-is.